# Check if $-2$ belongs to $\lbrace\log_2(-x) : x > -1\rbrace$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to check if $-2$ belongs to this set: 
$$A=\{\log_2(-x) : x > -1\}.$$

Question: $-2 \in A$?

Here what comes to my mind.
First of all I know that the $\log$ argument must be $>0$ so my conditions are $x>-1 , x>0$ so I can consider only $x>0$.

Now to verify the request I should set

\begin{align*}
\log_2(-x) &= -2\\
&= -2\log_2 2\\
&= \log_2(2)^{-2}\\
&= \log_2{\frac{1}{4}},
\end{align*}

so
\begin{align*}
-x &= \frac{1}{4}\\
\implies x &= - \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align*}

So $-2 \notin A$ because the condition of $x>0$.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not right. The condition $x>0$ is *not* the right one, I think you mean $x<0$, because we are considering $\log_2 (-x)$. Thus, following your steps, we have that $-2 \in A$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't change the $>$ after considering the argument. Thanks!

Comment: @Christian Giupponi You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

for $y=log_2(t)$,domain of function must be $> 0$, i.e. $t > 0$ ,so for  set A, from $-x>0$ and $x>-1$ we have $-1<x<0$, so when $x=-\frac{1}{4}$, we get $-2 \in A$